# command-line python SimpleHTTPServer gets quickly terminate

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to demo a simple website using the python SimpleHTTPServer module. However, the server almost immediately is terminated. I'm ssh'd into the box, type:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

the webserver starts:

`Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`

and then displays `Terminated` and shuts down within a few seconds.

I'm at a loss as to what to look for. I'm using this same command on macOS with no problems; this is on a Linux box running python V2.7.9.

Comment: Sounds like something else is sending a TERM signal to your program

Comment: For sure; the question is how to track that down :=)